# asp.net MVC areas separate app pool

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, iis-7.5

Is it possible to set separate application pool for each Areas in a MVC 4 app hosted under IIS 7/7.5? If yes, how? I tried to convert Area1 (http:// app/area1) as "Web Application" and assign a separate pool than Area2 (http:// app/area2) but when I check the identity using Request.ServerVariables["APP_POOL_ID"], it shows the default app pool name where the "app" is hosted.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt it, the binaries live in the root of the app, so they will always be executed as that app pool identity.

You will need to host the binaries in the area, which probably means that you can't do it with areas, but will need to refactor the areas into complete web apps and then use them that way, either way, you are not going to be able to share models/views that easily.

You can probably put your views in a separate project and then compile them using something like razorgenerator, i've not tried anything like that yet, but i believe some have had good results going that route.

Comment: Thanks Slicksim for you response! Yes, I thought of going that route but it seems unclean. :) So wanted to make sure.